# Online job application systems

Tags: job-search

Some tenure track positions require you to submit a CV and fill out online forms with the same information. Do search committees use the online information or just the supporting CV and teaching and research statements?

Comment: Is this something that the work.SO might have some insight on for you?  Possibly worth a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think both. Scanning lists of applicants within the electronic system, only the info entered is visible. Only when looking more fully at an individual file (as opposed to scanning aggregate lists of applicants) is the "custom" information visible. So it's good to take the trouble to be sure that the "entered" information is accurate, otherwise the CV itself may never be seen, etc.